# Similar URL, different content, same keyword - bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, url

I'm thinking about adding a page to my website, this will be extremly good for users, but could this be bad for seo?

Page 1 (currently exists, ranks good):

- URL: `example.com/formula-1`
- Title: Formula 1
- Focus Keyword: Formula 1
- Content: news list (wordpress category page)

Page 2 (I want this to rank better):

- URL: `example.com/formula1`
- Title: Formula 1 - The Season
- Focus Keyword: Formula 1
- Content: overview on the season, with details on the races, classifications etc. + top news of the season

Comment: What would be the point of this??

Comment: I'm thinking about setting up a website in this way, need to understand if this can be good for seo or not. From an user friendly point of view, it's. From a SEO point of view?

Comment: @testermaster: Why do you think this is good for users? It’s a good practice to design URLs in such a way that users can know what the page will be about just by looking at the URL. How’s a user supposed to know the difference in content when seeing `/formula-1` and `/formula1`?

Comment: Actually, you're right :) Problem is, `/formula-1` is existing and for some reasons I can't change it (neither with a 301 redir), unless it's EXTREMLY important to do this for SEO reasons considering the new page. So, the new page has to have the best URL possible, and it's `/formula-1` (occupied) or `/formula1`... Users will notice the `/formula-1` URL only after some time, when they'll be addicted to our website's structure, so it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you update the content of your website.

Wether this is good or not can not be told by us. It depends on "Why does the page score good *now*?" and "Will the new page score good as well?".
We might be able to answer the first one, but we can't just see the new version.

**You have a few options:**

- Upload the new version as a whole and hope for the best. Ofcourse you can do your checks, validations, let someone else look at it to decrease the risk.
- A/B test. Create a way so that some pages have the new format and see how they do. This does require some more technical work in order to work.
- Incrementally pass the changes. First you just do your new menu and wait. Then update 2 and wait, etc. This takes more time to deploy which is less spectacular, but it has advantages:

  - You can see the effect of each change, and roll back if needed
  - You (visibly) maintain your site, which is interesting for both a bot and a user.

Might be good to keep in mind that Search Engines try to score as a normal person as good as they can. They'll try to rate you on how interesting you are for a user. You say your new page is a lot more interesting for your users, your statistics should reclect that, and if so, you should notice a better ranking.

Comment: I'm thinking about canonical URL. Basically, the new page would be a lot better for new visitors, while the old one is better for regular visitors. So, with a canonical URL (from the old one to the new one) I should be safe, right? If I upload the page, see how it does, and add the canonical URL only in a second time, how much will it take to have effect? The thing I'm worried the most is the fact that the URLs are similar, but would be important to have them like this.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a page :

**Page 1 (currently exists, ranks good):**

URL: example.com/formula-1
Title: Formula 1
Focus Keyword: Formula 1
Content: news list (wordpress category page)

Now according to what i understand, the above page provides the list of episodes or formula 1 series. And you want to create a new page for the information about the formula 1 series.

So what i would recommend is to add this description/content on the top of existing page, like an overview of the season and the below that can be a listing for the episodes. This will improve the visibility of this page and avoid duplication and provide a good user experience as well.

But if you want to know seo intricacies of creating the another one. It wont hurt your seo as both have different content and purpose. But you should ideally take a new url structure for these kind of urls like :

example.com/formula-1/ - > can give a brief about season
example.com/formula-1/seasons -> can give list of seasons

**But still i would go with one unified page.**

Comment: Problem for the unified page: users that knows everything about F1 and are regular visitors wouldn't like to see all the time some kind of information. They want only the latest news and rumors.
Users that don't know F1 and/or came to our website for the first time by google would like all the details.

Basically, the new page will be a lot more interesting for new visitors, while for regular visitors the news lists would be better.

Comment: Then the first solution works, create two separate pages and make them meaningful...urls also should represent the content in them...like i mentioned in my answer...

example.com/formula-1/
example.com/formula-1/episodes/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating a static page 2 which contains content like an article. But, seriously what's the point here you want to rank 2 pages on google for same Keyword. Is that what you want? It's better you should modify the first page so well that it become good for both of the pages.

Comment: Sounds like testermaster understands his audience and believe creating a page in this way will be well received - OP's question is 'will this be good or bad for seo?'... not 'what would be the best seo strategy to rank for given keywords?'.

Comment: I don't want to rank both pages. The new page should rank better than the old one. I want to create it because it would be better for users that reach us the first time via google. While for regular visitors would be better the simple news list.